# How to Check If the connected router is changed

Tags: android, network-programming, router

I'm making a project in order to check Wi-fi connectivity ranges in my University.

My biggest problem right now is I have to check whether or not I'm connected to a new router while I walk inside the campus.

Since all routers in the school is actually part of one single internet and they have the same name when connectivity is low it just automatically connects to the closest router.

How can I identify if connected to another router in school when I change places?
Is ther some broadcaster function maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The MAC address is changes when you connect to other router.
You can get the current MAC like this:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = 
(WifiManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
    WifiInfo wInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress(); 
}
```

You may want to check this after connectivity changed. Get it from CONNECTIVITY_ACTION Broadcast receiver (API>24)  `